# Unable to get out from crontab command

Tags: cron

I am using a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Whenever I type:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

OR

```
sudo -u www-data crontab -e
```

The command prints some number and nothing else.
And whatever you do to try to exit from it, by any means, you are not able to do.

**Questions**

- First of all, How to exit from above command? I am just stuck.
- Why the command is not showing the crontab entries?
- How to make the above command to show crontab entries?

**EDITED**
I have chosen the editor as vim.basic with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

But when I do `echo $EDITOR` prints empty.

Also,
`crontab -e` -> works fine
`sudo -u www-data crontab -e` -> stuck as mentioned above

Comment: CROSS POST? This is the only place I have posted.

Comment: IRC n Forums are two different entities.

Comment: @MagePsycho If it responds to ESC and then `:` type of  key sequence, then it's vim, so use ESC then `:` then `q` to exit.

Comment: Stupid question: Why didn't you install [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04)?

Comment: This is in the production server. And I have running my sites on 16.04 LTS. Will try 18.04 though in future.

Comment: @guiverc we do not own the internet. There's a rule against cross posting on multiple SE sites, but we can' hardly expect someone to ask here and nowhere else in the whole internet! And do avoid YELLING, it isn't very pleasant.

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that your default editor is not set and is defaulting to `ed`.

What do you get if you run:

```
env | egrep 'EDITOR|VISUAL'

sudo env | egrep 'EDITOR|VISUAL'

sudo -u www-data env | egrep 'EDITOR|VISUAL'
```

The way to quit from `ed` is to type: `q`<kbd>↵ Return</kbd>

To set a different editor, you could do:

```
sudo -u www-data EDITOR=$EDITOR crontab -e
```

Answer (score 3):

> First of all, How to exit from above command? I am just stuck.

We don't know what editor you are using. Try `Esc :q` (vim) or `Ctrl-x` (nano) or `Ctrl-x Ctrl-c` (emacs) or `q` (`ed`).

- Run command `select-editor` and choose an editor you want to use
- Alternative: set environment variable `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` to an editor of your liking.
  Example: `export EDITOR=emacs` to use emacs or `export EDITOR=nano` for nano.
- Then, run `crontab -e` to edit your crontab
- Use `crontab -l` to show the content of your crontab

Comment: I am logged in as `sudo` user. `echo $EDITOR` -> gives blank.

Comment: Yes, that's the default. What does `select-editor` tell you?

Comment: I have added more details. Please check.

Comment: Login as `www-data` and add the environment variable to ~/.profile using `echo -e "\nexport EDITOR=vim" >> ~/.profile`. Then logout. Then try `sudo -u www-data crontab -e` again.

Comment: I have many users for crontab entries. Is there a way to set the default for all (system wide)?

Comment: You can edit `/etc/profile` for login-shells and `/etc/bash.bashrc` for non-login shells.

Answer (score 1):

I have applied the following commands

```
# Interactive way
update-alternatives --config editor
# And choose 3 (vim.basic)

# Non Interactive way
sudo update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/vim.basic

# Verify as
sudo update-alternatives --query editor
```

Alternatively, you can add it in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file and reload to reflect the changes.

```
export VISUAL=vim
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"
```

For crontab for `www-data` user, I am using as:

```
sudo crontab -u www-data -e
```

And this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use crontab -e

- unless you know exactly how your system, account and session are configured you don't know what happens next.
- Change any one of these and something different can happen
- even if it does open your crontab in an editor you can operate, it can be tricky to abandon the changes

Instead, write the crontab to temporary file, use the editor of your choice, import the file back into cron:

```
$ crontab -l >mycron
$ vi mycron
$ crontab <mycron
```

(I would also STRONGLY recommend not running cron jobs as the www-data user)